# How to find the number of upstream tasks failed in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I am having a tough time in figuring out how to find the failed task for the same dag run running **twice** on same day(**same execution day**).

Consider an example when a dag with `dag_id=1` has failed on the first run (due to any reason lets say connection timeout maybe) and task got failed. TaskInstance table will contain the entry of the failed task when we try to query it. GREAT!!

But, If I re-run the same dag(note that dag_id is still 1) then in the last task(it has the rule of `ALL_DONE` so irrespective of the whether upstream task was failed or was successful it will be executed) I want to calculate the number of tasks failed in the current dag_run ignoring the previous dag_runs. I came across dag_run id which could be useful if we can relate it to TaskInstance but I could not. Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: How/where would you like to calculate this? Inside the process or just in Python in general?

Comment: Inside the process as a part of the dag. May be for some reporting purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `PythonOperator` task which queries the Airflow database to find the information you're looking for. This has the added benefit of passing along the information you need to query for the data you want:

```
from contextlib import closing
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.utils.state import State

def your_python_operator_callable(**context):    
  with closing(settings.Session()) as session:
    print("There are {} failed tasks in this execution".format(
      session.query(
        models.TaskInstance
      ).filter(
        models.TaskInstance.dag_id == context["dag"].dag_id, 
        models.TaskInstance.execution_date == context["execution_date"],
        models.TaskInstance.state == State.FAILED).count()
      )
```

Then add the task to your `DAG` with a `PythonOperator`.

(*I have not tested the above, but hopefully will send you on the right path*)

Answer (score 6):

In Airflow 1.10.x the same result can be achieved by much simpler code that avoids touching ORM directly.

```
from airflow.utils.state import State

def your_python_operator_callable(**context):    
    tis_dagrun = context['ti'].get_dagrun().get_task_instances()
    failed_count = sum([True if ti.state == State.FAILED else False for ti in tis_dagrun])
    print(f"There are {failed_count} failed tasks in this execution"
```

The one unfortunate problem is that `context['ti'].get_dagrun()` does not return instance of DAGRun when running test of a single task from CLI. In the effect, manual testing of that single task will fail but the standard run will work as expected.

Comment: can this be done with docker operators as well? @heavelock

Comment: What do you mean? You want to run code I provided within docker operator or you want to check state of docker-operator tasks? 

If the former - probably yes, but it doesn't make sense in my opinion. If the latter then yes, this function is operator agnostic as it only is touching the task instances.